# Error during running test cases from Test Manager: "The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required."

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, microsoft-test-manager

While executing test cases from TM the following error occurs:

"The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required."

Configuration: TFS 2015, TFS 2013 agent and controller, VNext build systems

Event viewer on test controller has the following errors:

ControllerConfiguration: Agent 'vstfs:///LabManagement/TestMachine/19' attempted to connect but failed: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Exceptions.EqtException: The agent can connect to the controller but the controller cannot connect to the agent because of following reason: No such host is known. Make sure that the firewall on the test agent machine is not blocking the connection.

Firewall is on both test agent and controller VMs.

(QTController.exe, PID 1596, Thread 9) TcmRunner: Error starting the test run: The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required..

But the test agent and controller are installed of same version 12.0.40629.0

Build drop location is accessible from the TFS Controller machine for the user configured.

Able to ping test agent vm from test controller vm and vice versa.

Any suggestions or work around in order to resolve this issue would be helpful and much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run automated tests from a TFS 2015 ("vNext") build via MTM. Only XAML builds are supported.